# Stored procedure returning result even thought it's not supposed to

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, logical-operators

I have a stored procedure which looks like following:

```
ALTER PROCDURE [dbo].[zsp_selectallupceans_listProduction]
    (@UPCList NVARCHAR(4000),
     @EANList NVARCHAR(4000),
     @Type TINYINT)
AS
    SELECT  
        dd.UPC, dd.EAN, dd.EBAYID AS ItemID
    FROM
        ThirdPartyData AS dd 
    WHERE 
        EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.SplitStringProduction(@UPCList,',') S1 
                WHERE dd.UPC = S1.val) 
        OR EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.SplitStringProduction(@EANList,',') S2 
                   WHERE dd.EAN = S2.val) 
        AND dd.Type = @Type
```

The parameters are passed like following:

```
@UPCList='709127309019',
@EanList='0709127309019',
@Type=4
```

The "SplitStringProduction" function looks like this:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[SplitStringProduction]
    (@string NVARCHAR(MAX),
     @delimiter NVARCHAR(5)) 
RETURNS @t TABLE
           (
                val NVARCHAR(500)
           )
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @xml XML
    SET @xml = N'<root><r>' + replace(@string,@delimiter,'</r><r>') + '</r></root>'

    INSERT INTO @t(val)
       SELECT
           r.value('.','varchar(500)') AS item
       FROM
           @xml.nodes('//root/r') as records(r)

    RETURN
END
```

Now when I do a simple select from my table like following:

```
select * 
from thirdpartydata dd
where dd.UPC = '709127309019' -- note this is one of the parameters passed to the stored procedure...
```

I will get only 1 result with a column `Type` set to "1"....

Now when I try out my stored procedure:

```
exec  zsp_selectallupceans_listProduction '709127309019','0709127309019',4
```

I still get 1 result, even though I'm not supposed to get any result, because if you can see the "Type" parameter is set to 4, thus no matching records should be found....

What am I doing wrong here, I can't seem to figure it out ??

Comment: As you are using OR you're missing some parentheses and it's not evaluating as you are expecting. It's found the UPC so returning a row, i think you want to enclose both EXISTS in ()

Comment: When using `AND` and `OR` in a `where` clause, you should always add parantheses: `WHERE (1=1 OR 2=2) AND x=y`.

Comment: `X OR Y AND Z` is the same as `X OR (Y AND Z)` in just the same way as `X + Y * Z` is the same as `X + (Y * Z)`. Always add braces, make the order of precidence explicit, not implicit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to enclose the `OR` condition inside parenthesis:

```
WHERE (
      EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.SplitStringProduction(@UPCList,',') S1 WHERE dd.UPC=S1.val) 
   OR EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.SplitStringProduction(@EANList,',') S2 WHERE dd.EAN=S2.val) 
) AND dd.Type = @Type
```

Without them your query like this:

```
WHERE EXISTS (...) 
   OR (EXISTS (...) AND dd.Type = @Type)
```

And the result your get is because the first OR condition matches.